# what does "become amazing with" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> You want to change something in your life and finally ***become amazing with*** women.

What does "become amazing with" mean in the above sentence?

Comment: It's like *get along with women,* or together with *women*, you success.

Comment: It means approximately that you will be regarded as "amazing" by women or you will achieve "amazing" success with women. It's advertising rhetoric conrived to be at once as vague as possible and as suggestive as possible, so you will "fill in the blanks" with your own fantasies of being "amazing", whatever they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To become amazing with suggests that you are really good at something

And in this case since it is "with woman" It could mean that he is amazing at Romancing women or talking to women.